# Asp net core 6 with remote mariaDB database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mariadb-10.5

I need to connect with a mariaDB database which is hosted online with entity framework core 6.

here my connection string:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnection": "Server=148.163.126.69;Port=3306;Database=dbname;Uid=db_admin;Pwd=pass;connect timeout=100;default command timeout=200;"
  },
```

first part of program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UsersContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"),
     ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
    });
});
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

I already tried to connect with a local SQLServer and it works fine.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Borka forgot to add it, just edited the post.

Comment: did you check if the server is accepting external connections?

Comment: I allowed all IPs to access the database via cpanel=>Remote Sql. I added '%' wildcard.

Comment: can you try to connect with another program, like some db explorer, but installed on your machine

Comment: @Borka I tried to connect with HeidiSQL but with no success, error 10060.

Comment: so basically the server refuses your connection. check if there's a firewall or something

Comment: @Borka I deactivated the firewall completely. I'm connecting to a shared server , I'm not sure if that would cause a problem.